# Как оптимизировать конкурентную вставку записей с индексом по ключу из последовательности?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure, oracle18c

Есть такая таблица и к ней последовательность:

```
create table t1 (id number constraint pkt1 primary key, name varchar2 (16))
/
create sequence t1seq 
/
```

Для вставки в таблицу есть процедура, которая упрощённо выглядит так:

```
create or replace procedure populateTable as
begin
    for i in 1..100000 loop 
        insert into t1 values (t1seq.nextval, dbms_random.string ('U', 16)); 
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Таблица постоянно запополняется. Причём, источников данных обычно несколько, они часто запускают процедуру одновременно в разных сессиях.

Значение первичного ключа, которое монотонно увеличивается, приводит к ряду проблем:

- Процедуры в разных сессиях постоянно пытаются записать один и тот же блок с самым правым листочным узлом индекса, что приводит к поочерёдному ожиданию доступа к блоку (т.н. *hot block*), и как результат, снижению проиизводительности.
- значение `PCT_USED` в статистике индекса довольно высокое - более 90%. В первую очередь потому, что частая запись максимального значения индексируемого ключа приводит к тому, что при запоненнии блока с самым правым листочным узлом, он не разбивается (*split 50-50*), а добавляется новый блок (*split 90-10*).

Какие есть пути решения?

Answer (score 2):

В 18c для создания последовательностей добавлены две новые опции: `SCALE` и `EXTEND`.
Подробнее в гл. [24.2.4.3 Making a Sequence Scalable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/admin/managing-views-sequences-and-synonyms.html#GUID-76663C84-D792-46A3-A25A-03C49DED71AD). Предистория в [базе идей](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/2548).

Они были добавлены для устранения негативных эффектов с монотонно увеличивающимися последовательностями:

> A scalable sequence is particularly efficient when used to generate unordered primary or unique keys for data ingestion workloads having high level of concurrency. [...] Scalable sequences significantly reduce the sequence and index block contention and provide better data load scalability [...]

Сравним на примере. Подготовка таблиц, последовательностей и тестовой процедуры:

```
create table t1 (id number constraint pkt1 primary key, name varchar2 (16))
/
create sequence t1seq 
/
create table t2 (id number constraint pkt2 primary key, name varchar2 (16))
/
create sequence t2seq scale extend
/
create or replace procedure populate (tabnum int) as
begin
    for i in 1..500000 loop case tabnum 
        when 1 then insert into t1 values (t1seq.nextval, dbms_random.string ('U', 16)); 
        when 2 then insert into t2 values (t2seq.nextval, dbms_random.string ('U', 16)); end case;
        commit;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Тестовую процедуру запустить одновременно в двух или более сессиях:

```
exec populate (1) --exec populate (2)
```

Посмотреть в истории сессий, какие события наступали чаще
(более релевантно для вопроса: `enq: TX - index contention`):

```
define sessions=sid1,sid2, ... sidn
select nvl (sh.event, 'on CPU') event, o.object_name object, count (*) waits
from v$active_session_history sh 
join user_objects o on o.object_id = sh.current_obj# 
where sh.session_id in (&sessions) and event is not null
and sh.sample_time > sysdate-60/(24*60) 
group by sh.event, o.object_name 
order by waits desc
```

После выполнения, провести анализ индексов:

```
analyze index pkt1 validate structure; -- pkt2 
 
select name, lf_blks, pct_used 
from index_stats
/
```

Результаты показывают, что значительно увеличилось кол-во листочных узлов при снижении заполнености индекса, что свидетельствует о преобладании нормального разбиения листочных блоков (split 50-50):

```
NAME    LF_BLKS   PCT_USED
---- ---------- ----------
PKT1       2013         94
PKT2       5342         69
```

---

PS В выпуске 12c это расширение было добавлено, но было не документированно и оффициально не поддерживалось. Те, кто работает с 12c, могут попробовать эти новые опции в тестовой среде.